# Different OS and Server Path

Tags: php, windows, linux, apache, iis

in windows (using apache as server), my file path directory will be C:\xampp\htdocs\mysvn\PhpDocumentor\phpdoc.php. But what happen with other OS such as linux on APACHE, or IIS on windows, Or other OS i don't know and never use ?

i would like to know to make sure i wrote the bullet proof, file reading via PHP.

Care anyone give an example path according to different OS and Server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often create a configuration file for each project, and inside that define some paths in a few constants. Use those constants any time you want to include files from then on:

```
// config.php
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('LIBS', ROOT . '/libs');

// some other file.php
include LIBS . '/mylib.php';
```

Though Windows typically uses backslashes as path separators, it's smart enough to handle both, so using forward slashes is safe.

Comment: @nickf, sorry i have edit the question. I believe your answer is right (before i edit them). But that's not what i'm asked for. Thanks for quick reply ;D

Comment: @justjoe: what's your question then? if you want to get the current file's directory just use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you more about this. My question is more about path structure in other OS. I know in APACHE in Windows but how about other OS / Server environment ? if you have experience about this, please share. i will be grateful

Comment: @justjoe - could you ask a question then? What do you actually want to know?? If you build your application properly it shouldn't matter at all what path is used for the www directory.

Comment: about the path, i hope so. i just want to be sure. My application work by reading files in the path. Mostly those files use php extension. When i work on localhost, i can not use www. I need to use path such as c:/xampp/htdocs/thefiles.php. So, i wonder about other os path (or maybe other servers). How different its path with my windows path ?

Comment: they will look something like `/var/www/thefiles.php` but like I said, use the above method and it shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: thanks now a i'm relieve ;D . thank you to you for answering my silly question